# Dynamic sitemap by language

Tags: reactjs, seo, multilingual, xml-sitemap

I have several static sitemap (one sitemap for one language, ie sitemap_en.xml, sitemap_de.xml) and i want to deserve a final static sitemap.xml (http://example.com/sitemap.xml) which targets good sitemap depending on language  (http://example.de/sitemap.xml --> sitemap_de.xml)

I am wondering how to do that in a react app, on a ssr way i can do

```
app.get('/sitemap.xml', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('good_path_to_correct_sitemap.xml');
});
```

Maybe there is a better solution to handle several static sitemap in a multilingual website with multi domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to centralize all of your sitemaps into one sitemap [index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712), quoting:

> If you have many sitemaps, you can use a sitemaps index file as a way
> to submit them at once. The XML format of a sitemap index file is very
> similar to the XML format of a sitemap file.

But in your case, since each language is served on a different domain, you can do a [cross submit](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location), quoting:

> By default, this will result in a "cross submission" error since you
> are trying to submit URLs for [www.host1.com](http://www.host1.com) through a Sitemap that is
> hosted on [www.sitemaphost.com](http://www.sitemaphost.com) (and same for the other two hosts). One
> way to avoid the error is to prove that you own (i.e. have the
> authority to modify files) [www.host1.com](http://www.host1.com). You can do this by modifying
> the robots.txt file on [www.host1.com](http://www.host1.com) to point to the Sitemap on
> [www.sitemaphost.com](http://www.sitemaphost.com).